# error in procedure SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, plsql

Why I'm getting Error(29,7):

> PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

on compilation of the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE paytermupdate
IS
  recordcount INT;
  BEGIN
    recordcount := 0;

    SELECT COUNT(1)
    INTO recordcount
    FROM temp_pay_term;

    IF recordcount > 0 THEN
      FOR x IN (SELECT r.ddocname
                FROM temp_pay_term p, docmeta d, revisions r
                WHERE 'p.pid' = 'd.xproject_id'
                   AND r.did = d.did)
      LOOP

        UPDATE docmeta
        SET paymentterm = p.paymentterm
        WHERE did IN (
          SELECT MAX(did)
          FROM revisions r, docmeta d
          WHERE r.ddocname = d.ddocname)
        GROUP BY X.ddocname;

      END LOOP;

      COMMIT;
    END IF;
  END paytermupdate;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'p.pid' = 'd.xproject_id'` should not be in single quote, any way this will not throw error but it is string comparison only, not column comparison

change it to `p.pid = d.xproject_id`

GROUP BY should be with Select only

```
UPDATE docmeta
      SET paymentterm = p.paymentterm
      WHERE did      IN
        ( SELECT MAX(did) FROM revisions r,docmeta d WHERE r.ddocname = d.ddocname
        GROUP BY X.ddocname);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have **GROUP** in **UPDATE** SQL. 
It has no sens also.